# Laravel Array to string conversion on multiple records

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to salve multiple records at once..

When I try to store multiple records it gives an error of array to string conversion.

This is the response I get from axios.

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "property_type_id" => 2
    "fee_value" => "123"
    "product_service_id" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "property_type_id" => 1
    "fee_value" => "3333"
    "product_service_id" => 1
  ]
]
```

```
$feeByPropertyType = $request->feeByPropertyType;

        foreach ($feeByPropertyType as $row)
        {
            $data[] = [
                'property_type_id' => $row['property_type_id'],
                'fee_value' => $row['fee_value'],
                'product_service_id' => 1
            ];
        }
PaymentTypeProductService::insert($data);
```

I have tried a few other methods as well but none of them have worked so far.

Any help from the community will be greatly appreciated, on how to correct this.

Comment: what is the final data structure you expect to be saved to the database?

Comment: @TharakaDilshan I have updated my question please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your `$data` to be like this.

```
[
  [
    'property_type_id' => 2,
    'fee_amount' => "123"
  ],
  [
    'property_type_id' => 1,
    'fee_amount' => "1312"
  ],
]
```

Comment: I have change my response to this

array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "property_type_id" => 2
    "fee_value" => "333"
    "product_service_id" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "property_type_id" => 1
    "fee_value" => "111"
    "product_service_id" => 1
  ]
]

But i'm still getting array to string converion.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if the data structure of the `$request->feeByPropertyType` data structure matches with the database tables structure, then you can simply use `DB` facade to insert multiple rows at once.

```
DB::insert($request->feeByPropertyType);
```